# I have multiple queries but I would like to have only 1 query that runs it all

Tags: sql, function, parameters

So I have a database and I would like to select the weight, problem is that I have different weights and I want to know if I can make it into 1 query. This here is 2 of the different weight Types I have and what I have done.

```
SELECT TOP (13) height, Sum(total weight) as 'total weight'
FROM dbo.combine
WHERE
FacilityType = 'male'
GROUP BY height
ORDER BY Sum(totalweight) DESC

SELECT TOP (13) height, Sum(total weight) as 'total weight'
FROM dbo.combine
WHERE
FacilityType = 'female'
GROUP BY height
ORDER BY Sum(totalweight) DESC
```

Comment: Please tag with proper database.

Comment: store the facility type list in a table.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GROUP BY` and window functions:

```
SELECT FacilityType, WasteStreamType, tonnes_hh
FROM (SELECT FacilityType, WasteStreamType, Sum(TonnesFromHHSources) as tonnes_hh,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FacilityType ORDER BY Sum(TonnesFromHHSources) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM dbo.combine c
      GROUP BY FacilityType, WasteStreamType
     ) fw
WHERE seqnum <= 13
```

Comment: @Albs . . . (1) That is silly.  This has all the information you need in a single table.  If you really need to split the data, you can use views.  (2) Your question only does `select` queries, no inserts or tables creates. 
 (3) One SQL statement in general cannot create multiple different tables.